# Why does trying to use Grape with Rails fail with "uninitialized constant API"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-grape

I would like someone to explain why this is happening in Rails (4.1.8) with Grape (0.10.1)

so this is my API:

`app/api/root.rb`:

```
module API
  class Root < Grape::API
    prefix 'api'
    mount API::V1::Root
  end
end
```

`app/api/v1/root.rb`:

```
module API::V1
  class Root < Grape::API
    version 'v1'
    mount API::V1::Users
  end
end
```

`app/api/v1/users.rb`:

```
module API::V1
  class Users < Grape::API
    format 'json'

    resource :users do
      desc "Return list of users"
      get '/' do
        User.all
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`config/routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount API::Root => '/'
end
```

and in my `application.rb` I added:

```
config.paths.add "app/api", glob: "**/*.rb"
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/api/*"]
```

and in that case I get the error: `NameError: uninitialized constant API`

---

**but if my code looks like:**

`app/api/root.rb` same as above

then `app/api/v1/root.rb`:

```
class Root < Grape::API
  version 'v1'
  mount Users
end
```

`app/api/v1/users.rb`:

```
class Users < Grape::API
  format 'json'

  resource :users do
    desc "Return list of users"
    get '/' do
      User.all
    end
  end
end
```

`config/routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Root => '/'
end
```

and `config/application.rb` same as above

Then everything works fine.

My question is why don't I need to specify modules inside `v1/root.rb` and also inside `v1/users` and also why I don't need to use `API::Root => '/'` in `config/routes.rb`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because `app/api` is the top-level folder for your API classes, not `app`.

From [Grape's documentation](https://github.com/intridea/grape#rails):

> Place API files into `app/api`. Rails expects a subdirectory that matches the name of the Ruby module and a file name that matches the name of the class. In our example, the file name location and directory for `Twitter::API` should be `app/api/twitter/api.rb`.

Therefore the correct location for an `API::Root` class would actually be `app/api/api/root.rb`, not `/app/api/root.rb`—though that *is* the correct location for a class in the top-level namespace, which is why the second example you give (with classes removed from the `API` module) works.

I recommend you keep your API classes together in their own module, though, and move them to a matching subfolder beneath `app/api`.

Comment: thank you, that makes sense. I've seen similar answer on some other question, but it didn't get to me. it's all clear and makes sense. thanks @Simon

Answer (score 6):

From [Grape's documentation](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape#rails-60):

For Rails versions greater than 6.0.0.beta2, `Zeitwerk` autoloader is the default for CRuby. By default `Zeitwerk` inflects `api` as `Api` instead of `API`. To make our example work, you need to uncomment the lines at the bottom of `config/initializers/inflections.rb`, and add `API` as an acronym:

```rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'API'
end
```

Comment: If you are following the tutorial [`Making a Rails API with Grape
`](https://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/making-a-rails-api-with-grap/) on Rails 6+ then this solution will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to put my files into `app/api/api`, but it wasn't working for me.

I found a solution by simply putting the `api` folder into the `controller` folder. I'm not 100% sure what the problem was, but my guess is that it has something to do with the auto-loaded paths.

Comment: check the @Simon's answer above. The reason why is quoted above as well. solved my problems

Comment: I know, but I was documenting my solution for anybody else, who'll come across the same problem and will not be able to solve it with Simon's answer.